# Finding pairs in an array

Tags: c

So what I am trying to do is make a code to find pair of numbers in an array. This code below works perfectly when there is a single pair of numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int arr[10], i, j, pairs = 0;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                pairs++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", pairs);
}
```

I want to make it so that it works when there are 3 same elements.
For example, `arr[5] = 1, 1, 1, 2, 2`
it should return 2 pairs (`1,1` and `2,2` with an extra 1 left out) but it returns 4 pairs instead with my code!

Comment: I suggest you to sort the array first and then simply check the adjacent numbers.

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line. I also recommend you take some more time to try and evaluate your algorithm with pen-and-paper, and try to come up with something that might work better first before attempting to write code.

Comment: The suggested input data *does* have 4 pairs.

Comment: of course: 1,1,1, makes 3 pairs. 1,x,1, then 1,1,x, then x,1,1 with your algorithm since you're not eliminating when counted.

Comment: 1) Shall a pair consist of two consecutive elements ? 2) May an element only be used in one pair ?

Comment: Why don't you put the values directly into a counting linked hash map? Then all the pairs would be `\sum_1^n \lfloor count/2 \rfloor` and you could calculate this in average `O(number of unique values)`.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question and wanted to play with it, especially as @Neil and I are on the same wavelength.

It’s a day later now, and since there are O(n log n) and O(n²) solutions posted, here’s an actual O(n) version (where n is actually the length of the hash table, not the input, which we don’t count).
<sub>Even if we did count it, though, it would be O(n+k) → O(n).</sub>
<sup>(The same thing happens with the other solutions too, which is why we don’t count the input.)</sup>

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// the histogram
enum { MAX_SAMPLES = 1000 };  // this should be overkill for the expected load factor
int values[ MAX_SAMPLES ];    // the sample value being counted
int counts[ MAX_SAMPLES ];    // non-negative, zero == value not sampled


void add( int value )
{
  int hash = abs( value ) % MAX_SAMPLES;  // simplest hash EVER

  for (int offset = 0;  offset < MAX_SAMPLES;  offset++)  // give up if table is saturated
  {
    int index = (hash + offset) % MAX_SAMPLES;

    if (counts[index] == 0)      // if found an empty spot:
      values[index] = value;     //   add the value

    if (values[index] == value)  // if found the value:
    {                            //
      counts[index] += 1;        //   increment value's count
      break;                     //   and done searching
    }
  }
}


int read_int()
{
  int value;
  scanf_s( "%d", &value );
  return value;
}


int main()
{
  // input list --> histogram
  for (int n = read_int();  n;  n--)
    add( read_int() );

  // Σ ⌊count / 2⌋ --> number of pairs
  int num_pairs = 0;
  for (int n = 0;  n < MAX_SAMPLES;  n++)
    num_pairs += counts[n] / 2;

  printf( "%d", num_pairs );
}
```

This solution has been condensed to the simplest terms. In particular:

- there is no error checking: no allocation error, no input failure, no hash table saturation
- uses a global, fixed size hash map for the histogram, meaning:

  - it cannot grow if needed
  - but all counts are conveniently automatically initialized to zero

This solution does have its drawbacks though:

- it requires extra O(k) space
- bad input can bog it down
  For example, if all inputs (mod table size) were the same value then every input would be a hash collision. More sophisticated management of the hash map would alleviate both problems, at the cost of added complexity (grow the hash map if overloaded or too many collisions detected).
  It would also help a lot if the table size were a prime number.

#### Input method

I don’t know if the input *must* be { n, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub> }, which is very common in academia, at least, but it annoys me.

I very much prefer input that doesn’t require the user to know how many items he or she intends to provide: just type them and press Enter. This is much more easily done than people realize:

1. input from command-line arguments (very, very convenient for testing/playing):

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  for (int n = 1;  n < argc;  n++)
    add( atoi( argv[n] ) );
```

2. input from a single line of text, which we then parse:

```
// using strtok

fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin );
for (char * token = strtok( s, " " );  token;  token = strtok( NULL, " " ))
  add( atoi( token ) );
```

```
// using sscanf

fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin );
for (int value, k, n = 0;  sscanf_s( s + n, "%d%n", &value, &k ) == 1;  n += k)
  add( value );
```

Both of these input solutions are easily combined into the same program:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  if (argc > 1)
    // get input from command-line arguments //
  else
    // get input from a single line of text //
```

Anyway, this solution is totally over-the-top for an introductory assignment, even with the pared-down global histogram object reducing lines of code.

**Ideally**, SO answers to homework questions should help the OP work his or her way through his or her own solution (instead of just being an “ooh, ooh, I can do that” dumping ground of other people’s solutions, making it no more than a free code-writing service for students). Hopefully this solution gives just another tool in the box to reason about future problems.

Comment: Um, I just looked at the time stamps on this post. Why did this pop up in my feed if it is so old?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are comparing each element one by one with every other element that's why you are getting your answer as 4.

To count pairs for three or more than three, one approach may be to sort the array then count the no of times that element has occurred and if the frequency is greater than 2 that means it forms a pair.
Here is the modified code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arr[10], i, j, pairs = 0,count=0,prev_element=0;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    // You need to sort the array here.

    prev_element = arr[0];
    count=1;
    for(i = 1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(prev_element==arr[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(count>=2)
                pairs+=count/2;
            else
            {
                prev_element=arr[i];
                count=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", pairs);
}
```

And this will also reduce the time complexity of the code. Previously the time complexity was O(n2) but now it will also become O(n).

Here, Firstly the no of times each element has occurred will be calculated and if the number of occurrences is greater than two than the element will form a pair otherwise not.

Comment: If I give the input `5` and `1 2 3 4 1` this code prints `0` which seems wrong

Comment: Needs to sort the array before processing. And also 1 1 1 1 should give 2 pairs, but the code will only report 1.

Comment: This program would work only for the above mentioned output.It would give wrong output if the array is `1 1 1 2 2 3 3`

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes, now the code should work fine.

Comment: I should add to this, sorting array is also fastest way if implemented correctly. The way OP has it is n^2, if you sort array, you are n log (n) + n for going through array which boils down to n log (n).

Comment: You cannot ignore the sorting of the array, which makes this, at best, O(n log n). It is _not_ the _fastest_ way, however: that belongs to using a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the pairs that are compared and counted. Otherwise, these pairs may be counted multiple times.

**The following code is working correctly.** Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arr[10], check[10], i, j, pairs = 0;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        check[i]    =   0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j] && check[j] ==  0   &&  check[i]    ==  0)
            {
                pairs++;
                check[j]    =   1;
                check[i]    =   1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", pairs);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int arr[10], i, j, pairs = 0;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    bubbleSort(arr,n);

    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
        {
            pairs++;
            /*Skip the paired index*/
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", pairs);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If the array is sorted

public class TestFindPairInSortedArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 9};
        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 4, 4};
        int target = 8;
        findPair(intArray, target);
    }

    private static void findPair(int[] intArray, int target) {
        int j = intArray.length - 1;
        boolean flag = false;
        if (intArray.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Not enough Elements");
        } else {
            if (intArray.length == 2 && intArray[0] + intArray[1] == target) {
                System.out.println("Pair Found at index 0 and 1");
            } else if (intArray.length == 2 && intArray[0] + intArray[1] != target) {
                System.out.println("No Pair Found");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; !flag; ) {
                    if (intArray[i] + intArray[j] == target) {
                        System.out.println("Pair Found");
                        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if (intArray[i] + intArray[j] > target) {
                        j--;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (i == j && !flag) {
                        System.out.println("No Pair Found");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In Array is not sorted and index is not required

import java.util.HashSet;

public class TestFindPairInUnsortedArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 4, 4};
        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 9};
        int target = 8;
        findPairInUnsortedArray(intArray, target);
    }

    private static void findPairInUnsortedArray(int[] intArray, int target) {
        HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        boolean flag = false;
        if (intArray.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Not enough Elements");
        } else {
            if (intArray.length == 2 && intArray[0] + intArray[1] == target) {
                System.out.println("Pair Found at index 0 and 1");
            } else if (intArray.length == 2 && intArray[0] + intArray[1] != target) {
                System.out.println("No Pair Found");
            } else {
                for (int j : intArray) {
                    if (set.contains(target - j)) {
                        System.out.println("Pair Found");
                        flag = true;
                    } else {
                        set.add(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            System.out.println("No Pair Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
If array is not sorted and indices are required

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestFindPairInUnsortedArrayUsingMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = new int[]{6, 1, 7, 15, 11, 9};
        int target = 10;
//      int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 4, 4};
//      int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 9};
//      int target = 8;
        findPair(intArray, target);
    }

    private static void findPair(int[] intArray, int target) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        boolean flag = false;
        if (intArray.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Not enough Elements");
        } else {
            if (intArray.length == 2 && intArray[0] + intArray[1] == target) {
                System.out.println("Pair Found at index 0 and 1");
            } else if (intArray.length == 2 && intArray[0] + intArray[1] != target) {
                System.out.println("No Pair Found");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                    if (map.containsKey(target - intArray[i])) {
                        flag = true;
                        System.out.println("Pair Found at " + map.get(target - intArray[i]) + " " + i);
                    } else {
                        map.put(intArray[i], i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            System.out.println("No Pair Found");
        }
    }
}
```